# How to update all MySQL table rows at the same time?

Tags: mysql

How do I update all MySQL table rows at the same time?

For example, I have the table:

```
id    |  ip    | port      |  online_status |
1     |  ip1   | port1     |                |
2     |  ip2   | port2     |                |
3     |  ip3   | port3     |                |
4     |  ip4   | port4     |                |
5     |  ip5   | port5     |                |
```

I'm planning to create cronjob and monitor some servers, but I don't know exactly how to update them all from the table at the same time. What are some examples on how to do that?

Comment: Your data comes from where, what is the data/information involved and what do you want to update? Not very clear from what you wrote. You can never really update all rows at the same time.

Comment: you need to provide more details, how you want it to be updated? what sort of columns/information you need to update?

Answer (score 36):

Omit the `where` clause:

```
update mytable set
column1 = value1,
column2 = value2,
-- other column values etc
;
```

This will give all rows the same values.

This might not be what you want - consider `truncate` then a mass `insert`:

```
truncate mytable; -- delete all rows efficiently
insert into mytable (column1, column2, ...) values
(row1value1, row1value2, ...), -- row 1
(row2value1, row2value2, ...), -- row 2
-- etc
;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for but is there a way that I can use truncate and then insert when I am not a root user? I found out that as a non root user, I cannot grant 'DROP' privileges, which is essential for 'truncate' command to work

Comment: @Priya If you have too many rows to `delete` them all in one transaction, with MySQL you can do the unconventional but awesome `delete from table limit 100000` (pick the largest limit that consistently works).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried this as well. But unfortunately even 'delete' privilege I do not have as a  non root user :( But I appreciate your response.

Comment: @Priya a) if you don’t even have delete privilege, why are you asking about how to delete rows? b) delete is a basic operation. Surely you can `grant delete on mytable to public` without cause for worry

Answer (score 32):

```
update mytable set online_status = 'online'
```

If you want to assign different values, you should use the TRANSACTION technique.

Comment: how about the number for example row 1 have 80 value then row 2 have 70 value, how i can change all data with add 5 point to all row ?

Answer (score 10):

The default null value for a field is "not null". So you must set it to "null" before you can set that field value for any record to null. Then you can:

```
UPDATE `myTable` SET `myField` = null
```

Answer (score 4):

```
UPDATE dummy SET myfield=1 WHERE id>1;
```

Comment: Please try to avoid code only answers by adding some explanation of why your code is the solution to the question. Remember this answer could help someone else in the future and the more information the better.

Comment: This won't actually update all the rows - it won't update where the ID is 1.

Comment: @ben is right, just make it >=, so your complete query would look like   "UPDATE dummy SET myfield=1 WHERE id >=1;"

Comment: @iWasCloud: Sure. But why keep the where clause at all, if the goal is to update all records?

Comment: @JeremyCaney yes, I don't actually remember why I wrote that maybe just to show this will also work the same as omitting the where clause. I have also added an answer that is without a where clause, also not sure why I added answer, the top-rated answer is better version.

Answer (score 3):

just use UPDATE query without condition like this

```
 UPDATE tablename SET online_status=0;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this,

```
UPDATE *tableName* SET *field1* = *your_data*, *field2* = *your_data* ... WHERE 1 = 1;
```

Well in your case if you want to update your online_status to some value, you can try this,

```
UPDATE thisTable SET online_status = 'Online' WHERE 1 = 1;
```

Hope it helps. :D

Answer (score 1):

Just add parameters, split by comma:

```
UPDATE tablename SET column1 = "value1", column2 = "value2" ....
```

see the link also
[MySQL UPDATE](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-data.aspx)